# Angular docker cannot reach backend service container

Tags: angular, docker, nginx

I have an angular SPA and a backend service, both are deployed via docker containers. I can't seem to get the angular app to connect to the backend service.

Using Nginx in the angular container, with the following configuration

```
server {

  root /usr/share/nginx/html/;

  location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
  }

  location http://backend-service {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

    proxy_pass http://backend-service:8080/;
  }
}
```

And the environment file for the angular app

```
export const environment = {
  api: 'http://backend-service',
};
```

The containers are linked and I can ping the backend container from within the Nginx/angular container by its service name, I think I've got something wrong in the nginx config file...

Any insight?

Comment: Does NGINX successfully return an error response? like 503 for example... just to verify NGINX is running and isn't the problem

Comment: Hitting a 404 on any endpoint which should be resolving on the backend service

Comment: good job with the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick in the end was to remove the docker reference from the environment file

```
export const environment = {
  api: '/api',
};
```

Then adjust the default.conf file to match:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name terrible-spa;
  root /usr/share/nginx/html/;
  index index.html index.html;

  location /api {
    proxy_pass http://backend-service:8080/api;
  }

  location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
  }
}
```

This will correctly forward all calls /api to the backend-service container.